# How to transform "Umlaute" (ü) to "ue" in the string?

Tags: string, replace, abap, non-ascii-characters

I have a string which is looking like this for example `Lübeck Nürnberg Österreich` with "Umlaute".

Now I want to `split` it and add the new "words" on the string like this `Lübeck Nürnberg Österreich Luebeck Nuernberg Oesterreich`.

So `ä` should be `ae`, `ö` should be `oe` and `ü` should be `ue`.

But I have no clue how to achieve this, thank you!

```
DATA: lt_split TYPE TABLE OF char40.

SPLIT string AT space INTO TABLE lt_split.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use REPLACE to replace a string with another string inside a string:

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURENCES OF: 'ä'
        IN string
        WITH 'ae',
        'ü'
        IN string 
        WITH 'ue'.
```

There is another variation of this statement, it can be used with an internal table:

```
REPLACE 'ä'
        IN TABLE lt_split
        WITH 'ae'.
```

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/de-DE/abapreplace_in_pattern.htm

Please note, the new string will be longer (if at least one replacement happened), this can be a problem, if the string was character type with fixed length and the new string would be longer, than allowed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function module `SCP_REPLACE_STRANGE_CHARS`, but you have less control than `replace` on what is changed.

Example:

```
  DATA name TYPE string.

  name = 'Lübeck Österreich Haßberge Eichstätt'.

  CALL FUNCTION 'SCP_REPLACE_STRANGE_CHARS'
    EXPORTING
      intext            = name
    IMPORTING
      outtext           = name
    EXCEPTIONS
      invalid_codepage  = 1
      codepage_mismatch = 2
      internal_error    = 3
      cannot_convert    = 4
      fields_not_type_c = 5
      OTHERS            = 6.

  ASSERT name = 'Luebeck Oesterreich Hassberge Eichstaett'.
```

Be careful, the function module affects lots of characters with accent and lots of special characters, for instance, depending on the values of parameters, we may have these replacements:

- á ==> AE
- ā ==> A (Acircumflex)
- Ă ==> Ae (Adieresis)
- £ ==> L (sterling)
- ß ==> ss (eszett)
- ¼ ==> 1/4

You may use the program `RSCP0007` to test the function module.